# Jquery onBlur pad zeros from the left into a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i using jquery to pad zeros from the left into a number to complete eleven digits just in case it did not have yet eleven digits?

How can i find the only one element i want to apply the eleven zeros? $(#myid) ? instead of input?

```
$(document).on('blur keyup', 'input', function() {
    padElevenZeros( $(this) );
});
```

Comment: Tried with this function but did not work, :  function pad(pad, str, padLeft) {
                      if (typeof str === 'undefined') 
                        return pad;
                      if (padLeft) {
                        return (pad + str).slice(-pad.length);
                      } else {
                        return (str + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
                      }
                    } and calling 'onBlur' => 'pad(00000000000, this.value(), true)'

Comment: Have you tried using `$('#myid')` instead of `$(this)`? What exactly do you need? The body of `padElevenZeros`?

Comment: actually i need to find a way to create the padElevenZeros function. about $(#myid) i am almost sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to call the function to add zeros on blur and keyup of the #myID input only? Or to only apply the function to add zeros to the #myID input, but to do it on all blur and keyup events?

```
    // fires on all blur and keyup events
    $(document).on('blur keyup', 'input', function() {
        $('#myID').addLeadingZeros(11);
    });

    // fires on blur and keyup events for #myID
    $(document).on('blur keyup', '#myID', function() {
        $(this).addLeadingZeros(11);
    });

    $.fn.addLeadingZeros = function(length) {
      for(var el of this){
        _value = el.value.replace(/^0+/,'');
        length = length - _value.length;
        if(length > 0){
          while (length--) _value = '0' + _value;
        }
        el.value = _value;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Yes i want to call the function to add zeros on blur and keyup of the #myID input only

Comment: Then you can use specify the id as a query selector; #myID; as the second argument to the on function call. $(document).on('blur keyup', '#myID', function()...

Comment: almost there i get at the console log : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).addLeadingZeros is not a function. what i was doing wrong is to write $('#myID') in the parameter as in: $(document).on('blur keyup', $('#myID'), function() {

Comment: I get now : Uncaught TypeError: this[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: This came from the line: for(var el of this){

Comment: it works on pure html, did not work into cakephp, the html is the same

Comment: Curious, did you get it working with CakePHP? I do not have that installed.

Comment: It must be the way CakePHP handle forms,  still trying, also, as is a not required field, i will search about the possibility to erase any value in the field, just to not submit 00000000000.

Answer (score 4):

try doing this

```
function addLeadingZeros(sNum, len) {
    len -= sNum.length;
    while (len--) sNum = '0' + sNum;
    return sNum;
}

$(document).on('blur keyup', '#myid', function() {
    addLeadingZeros($(this).val(),11);
});
```

Comment: Do i replace $(this) for $('#myid') ?

Comment: yes either replace $(this) or change your selector.

Comment: did not work, i type an id to the element and set : $(document).on('blur', $('#myid'), function() {/*blur keyup*/addLeadingZeros($('#myid'),11);});

Comment: $(document).on('blur', '#myid', function() { addLeadingZeros($(this),11);});

Comment: if your #myid is an input dont forget to put .val() with your selector ... as in addLeadingZeros($(this).val(),11);
if its a div or section then write .text()

Comment: I try but no leading zeros did appear